# Setting testfailure in testng gives positive return

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I want to set the test result of a method in testng to failure if there is an error. I found that this line of code should do the trick

```
Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
```

But if I provoke an error I will still get no failure returned from my total test run

```
===============================================
LoginTesten
Total tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

In the above run there should be 2 failures, but there is nothing. The rule to set the test result is in a different class then where the test is run from. It is set in a class where I put al my checkpage code so I that I have no bombastic test.

The code where it is set

```
public void checkTextOnPage(String text, boolean expected,String errorMessage, ArrayList<WebDriver> browsers, Logger Logger, String map) throws IOException {
        for(WebDriver driver: browsers){
            try {
                Assert.assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains(text), expected, errorMessage);
            }catch (AssertionError e){}
            Capabilities dataBrowser = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getCapabilities();
            if(driver.getPageSource().contains(text) == expected){
                Logger.info("[" + this.dateFormat.format(this.date) + "]" +" Browser:" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + " -- Version:" + dataBrowser.getVersion() + " -- Text : " + text + " => PRESENT");
            }else if (driver.getPageSource().contains(text) != expected){
                Logger.warning("[" + this.dateFormat.format(this.date) + "]" +" Browser:" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + " -- Version:" + dataBrowser.getVersion() + " -- Text : " + text + " => NOT PRESENT");
                File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(map + "text_" + text + "_NotPresent_" + this.screenshotCount + "_" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + ".png"));
                this.screenshotCount++;
                Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my test that is being run

```
public void loginIMWWelcomeNOT() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    this.getLogin().goToPage(this.getDriverList(), TestConstants.Test_URL);
    this.getBrowserMovement().typeTextElementXpath(".//*[@name='username']", this.getDriverList(), "intix1");
    this.getBrowserMovement().typeTextElementXpath(".//*[@name='password']", this.getDriverList(), "Jasmine11");
    this.getBrowserMovement().clickElementXpath(".//*[@name='logon']", this.getDriverList());
    this.getCheckPage().checkTextOnPage("grazjfnzeofnez", true, "We komen niet terecht op de welkom pagina", this.getDriverList(), this.getLOGGER(), this.getScreenshotMap());
    System.out.println(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult());
}
```

The output I get from that code is

```
apr 04, 2016 4:50:37 PM Data.CheckPage checkTextOnPage
WARNING: [2016-04-04 165030] Browser:chrome -- Version:49.0.2623.110 -- Text : grazjfnzeofnez => NOT PRESENT
[TestResult name="" status=FAILURE method=LoginTesten.loginIMWWelcomeNOT()[pri:0, instance:Data.Tests.LoginTesten@1e643faf] output={null}]
```

So it is being set but it's not picked up by anything. Is it the problem I set it in the other class or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stevedc Catch the error and then at the end of your test output it in the Assert failure as the error message. Something like

```
public void checkTextOnPage(String text, boolean expected,String errorMessage, ArrayList<WebDriver> browsers, Logger Logger, String map) throws IOException {
    for(WebDriver driver: browsers){
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains(text), expected, errorMessage);
        }catch (AssertionError e){}
        Capabilities dataBrowser = ((RemoteWebDriver)driver).getCapabilities();
        if(driver.getPageSource().contains(text) == expected){
            Logger.info("[" + this.dateFormat.format(this.date) + "]" +" Browser:" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + " -- Version:" + dataBrowser.getVersion() + " -- Text : " + text + " => PRESENT");
        }else if (driver.getPageSource().contains(text) != expected){
            Logger.warning("[" + this.dateFormat.format(this.date) + "]" +" Browser:" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + " -- Version:" + dataBrowser.getVersion() + " -- Text : " + text + " => NOT PRESENT");
            File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(map + "text_" + text + "_NotPresent_" + this.screenshotCount + "_" + dataBrowser.getBrowserName() + ".png"));
            this.screenshotCount++;
            Assert.assertEquals(true, false, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should not directly interact with your reporting. To indicate an error in JUnit, simply throw an exception or [asset in your tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593602/junit-test-what-is-failure).

Comment: But if I count on the assert it will just drop out of the test without any logging. I could catch it and add the logging but it's the same result the test will completly fail and I want to run it until the end

Comment: That the reponsibility of your build system, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174696/making-maven-run-all-tests-even-when-some-fail.